# How to add ngx-loading-bar as preloader into Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, loading, preloader

I have a project developed in Angular 6+, when user comes to website, first he sees logo and loading bar underneath it.
I have a problem switching to ngx-loading-bar insted of pace.js

Right now I am using Pace (the last example a fixed width line)
https://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/
integrated into the index.html of the root project.

I want to put ngx-loading-bar instead of pace to do same job.
ngx-loading-bar is already implemented and working when adding `<ngx-loading-bar></ngx-loading-bar>` in some of the components but not in the index.html.
I want to put same style same width loading bar as on example link bellow (4th bullet example, similar to pace) 
https://aitboudad.github.io/ngx-loading-bar/
so on the load, users sees the loading bar how it loads and on load, it goes on the next component as project example bellow.

Here is the example of project
www.wowlectures.com/pitchdeck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want it to work in index.html, do it in app.component.

You could create a loading service. A simple way is this:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class LoadingService {
  private _loading = true;

  get isLoading() {
    return this._loading;
  }

  set isLoading(v: boolean) {
    this._loading = v;
  }
}
```

Then in app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public loading: LoadingService) {}
}
```

And app.component.html:

```
<any-loading-component *ngIf="loading.isLoading"></any-loading-component>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

A cleaner way is to use subjects/observables in the service and subscribe to changes where you want to show the loading-bar and dispatch from anywhere you want it to start loading.

Comment: I will try to develop this and let you know how it goes here. Thank you for helping out!

Comment: It works well. I had a problem with the loading service. 
How to achieve bar to load for let's say 3seconds and then transfer to root?

Answer (score 0):

```
<app-root>
          <ngx-loading-bar></ngx-loading-bar>
        </app-root>
```

hey you can add this in your index.html